# How to get form elements by name in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have this form

```
var sformElem = $('form[name="search_form"]')[0];
```

I am able to access the form element of name say 'fieldname' by

```
var inputField = sformElem.fieldname;

    if (inputField) {  // true
    alert("this is true"); 
    }
```

But when I am trying to acess the value using val() method of jquery, javascript crashes.

**inputField.val()** is not defined.

but doing **inputField.value** returns the value

Why didn't val() method work?
Where am I making a mistake?
Also, please suggest the most appropriate of accesing form elements by name.

One method I know of is

```
$("#form2 input[name=name]")
```

but here we get the form by id and input fields by name.

I want to get both form and form elements by name.

Comment: Post your HTML also...

Comment: `.val()` is a jQuery method, while the `sFormElem.fieldname` is a plain DOM element.

Comment: Use `var sformElem = $('form[name="search_form"],input[name="name"]');` to get both the form and its input elements by name. Or just `var sformElem = $('[name="search_form"],[name="name"]');`

Answer (score 5):

*Why didn't val() method work?*

`inputField.val()` returned "not defined" because `inputField` is a DOM element and not a jQuery object. DOM elements don't have `val()` method. So the error is correct.

You need to convert it into a jQuery object. like

```
$(inputField).val()
```

*I want to get both form and form elements by name.*

```
var elem = $('form[name="search_form"] input[name=name]');
```

Comment: @Satpal Are you sure that `inputField` is a DOM element? Looks more like a plain string to me. Is that why you got downvoted? I don't know; not an expert.

Comment: @GreatBigBore, Sure `inputField` is a DOM element.

Answer (score 2):

Do `$(inputField).val()` as this passes the DOM Element through to jQuery therfore making `val` available

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = $("form[name = "search_form"]).get(0)

$("form[name = "search_form"]).get(0)
```

Since it is not a jquery object val will not work.Inorder to use val you have to make it a jquery object.

Like

```
$(x).val();
```

With this you will get the DOM Element

Answer (score 0):

get it done by using

```
$('inputField id or class').attr('attribute');
```

the class or input field value can be called by the `.attr()` method so that you can have that value in some variable.

Comment: This post is being automatically flagged as low quality because it is so short. Would you mind expanding it by adding some text to explain how it solves the problem?